# Do all of the properties stated below need to be met for a matrix to be characterized as invertible or only one being met is okay?

Tags: linear-algebra

- A is an invertible matrix
- A is row equivalent to the identity matrix
- A has n pivot columns The equation has only a trivial solution to
  ax=0
- The columns of A are linearly independent
- The equation Ax=b has at least one solution for each b in Rn
- The column of A span Rn maps Rn onto Rn
- There is a nxn matrix C such that CA is equal to the
  identity matrix
- There is an nxn matrix D such that AD is equal to the
  identity matrix

Comment: Each one is equivalent to every other one

Comment: As @FShrike comments, these are all equivalent. It's a good exercise to show that.